# Mpdf output 2 files

Tags: php, mpdf

I am generating a pdf file with mpdf, and need to save two files; one with water mark and one without water mark. Prossible?

```
<?php
if ($_POST['send'] == 1) { // no watermark
  $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true; // Not working
  $mpdf->Output($fileName,'F');
}

$mpdf->Output($fileName,'F'); // with watermark
?>
```

Comment: $mpdf->showWatermarkText = false; .. is not working.

Comment: Can you post more complete code sample? How are you setting the watermark text? How do you create your $mpdf object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<?php
if ($_POST['send'] == 1) { // no watermark
  $mpdf->showWatermarkText = false; 
  $mpdf->Output($fileName,'F');
}

$mpdf->SetWatermarkText('DRAFT');
$mpdf->showWatermarkText = true; 
$mpdf->Output($fileName,'F'); // with watermark
?>
```